# DrawerLayout не перехватывает событие onTouchEvent

Tags: android, drawerlayout, ontouchlistener

Одной из своих `Button` я назначил `OnTouchListener` и теперь, когда я выдвигаю боковую панель (`DrawerLayout`), одновременно срабатывает и `Button`. `OnTouchListener` был назначен для того, чтоб обрабатывалось исключительно нажатие кнопки. 
Как сделать так, чтоб `DrawerLayout` перехватывал `onTouch` у кнопок (кнопки расположены на основном `Activity`)? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: зачем onTouch если есть onClickListener?

Comment: Просто мне нужно отдельно обрабатывать DOWN и UP. Я новичок, поэтому другого способа пока не нашел

Comment: я с таким не сталкивался, но предположу, что выдвигаясь - боковая панель заставляет среагировать колбек onTouch, попробуйте закинуть панель в фрагмент, или диалог, чтобы посмотреть, в этом ли дело. Если да, то уже сможете исходить из чего-то

Answer (score 2):

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            // действие при нажатии на кнопку
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

button.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

`.ACTION_DOWN` - состояние кнопки, их много, студия подскажет =)

**UPD**

Чтобы сделать анимацию нажатия(уменьшения) кнопки сделайте следующее:
В папке `drawable` создайте **`button_test.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_t" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_t" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_n" />
</selector>
```

где `_t` картинка состояния нажатой кнопки, `_n` - отпущенного, нормального.
И далее в разметке активити или где Ваша кнопка находится установите аттрибут у этой кнопки

```
<Button
        ../
        android:background="@drawable/button_test"
        /..
/>
```

**UPD2**

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            button.setScaleX(0.5f);
            button.setScaleY(0.5f);
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            button.setScaleX(1.0f);
            button.setScaleY(1.0f);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

button.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял - мне не следовало вешать OnTouchListener на Activity и button.setOnTouchListener(this). А вместо этого сделать как указано выше? Сейчас попробую

Comment: @ВладВитвицкий, создаете в `onCreate` `listener` и вешаете его там же на Ваши нужные кнопки, как выше в примере.

Comment: Не помогло. Понимаю, что при движении пальца кнопки не должны реагировать, как при OnClickListener. Как этого добитmся с OnTouch?

Comment: @ВладВитвицкий, по сути, `Drawer` не должен никак трогать кнопки активити в момент выдвижения, он их должен перекрывать. Может в самом коде `Drawer` Вы что-то лишнее приписали.

Comment: Попробую спросить иначе. Как сделать так чтоб кнопка при нажатии (касании) уменьшалась, а при отпускании возвращалась к первоначальным размерам. Попробовал OnKeyListener, реакции нет вообще.

Comment: @ВладВитвицкий, обновил выше пост.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не то что мне нужно. Я пытаюсь проделать это с помощью view.setScaleX(1.8f);

Comment: @ВладВитвицкий, обновил еще пост выше. Масштаб можно изменять и таким образом. Можно также через ресурсы в коде.

Comment: Я так и сделал. Однако если палец поднести к краю экрана и выдвинуть боковую панель, при касании экрана реагирует также и кнопка (в данном случае вся Activity заполнена кнопками - как калькулятор). Поэтому про ресурсы можно по-подробней. Спасибо за терпение.

Comment: @ВладВитвицкий, можете [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread342555.html) почитать пример. Сам не пробовал. Но мне кажется что-то в коде `Drawer` не так. Кнопка не должна "зацепляться" при открытии меню.